# how to download the pipeline Artifacts from different job within the same pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have crated a archive in the different job of the same pipeline as follows

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
    displayName: Archive conda build
    inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'tar'
    tarCompression: 'bz2'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(packageName)$(Build.BuildId).tar.bz2'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

**Question:**

How can I download my archived file `$(packageName)$(Build.BuildId).tar.bz2'` from different part of the job int the pipeline?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Krzysztof's answer? Any update here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) and [Publish and download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

You will publish artifact in one job and download it in another.

Jobs may run on different agents thus you need to export/import them to some kind of shared disk.

[image: Azure pipelines basic]

Above steps will help you to achieve this.

Here you have an example how it may look:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - pwsh: |
        $content = 'Awesome artifact'
        New-Item -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Name "testsummary.md" -ItemType "file" -Value $content
    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: someArtifact

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: JB
    steps:
    - download: current
      artifact: someArtifact
    - bash: ls '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/someArtifact'
```